# IndentationError: expected an indented block где ошибка то?

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста

```
def getInput(digit, message):
    ret == ""
    while (ret =="" or not ret in digit):
        ret=input(message)
    return ret
print(f"Вы ввели число{getInput('12','Введите 1 или 2')}")
def getIntInput(minimum, maximum,message):
def loadMoney():
```

ошибка:
def loadMoney():                                                                                                        ^                                                                                                                   IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 2):

В последних строках вы вызываете функции? Если да, то делаете неправильно.
Функции вызывают так:

```
getIntInput(minimum, maximum,message)
loadMoney()
```

Если же вы пытаетесь создать функцию, то смотрите ответ @вася

Answer (score 1):

```
def getInput(digit, message):
    ret = ""
    while (ret =="" or not ret in digit):
        ret=input(message)
    return ret
print(f"Вы ввели число{getInput('12','Введите 1 или 2')}")
def getIntInput(minimum, maximum,message):
    pass
def loadMoney():
    pass
```

Comment: def loadMoney(): это другая функция , тем более после нее идут еще функции

Comment: @Андрей так у меня это другая функция, в чём проблема? Вынес в глобальный scope, если вы об этом.